# RelativeLayout, and side by side ListView/MapView

Tags: android

I try to put a `ListView` and a `MapView` side by side using `RelativeLayout`. However my `MapView` is always above the `ListView`.

Here is my main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:apiKey="0uZMgFMDqZETDVYg843CSoC8rHyuV01ypwz2C2Q"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:background="#fff" android:cacheColorHint="#fff"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false" android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Use `TableLayout` specify android:layout_weight="1" in both MapView and ListView

If you use Relative Layout then you have to set maximum width to both listview and map view programmatically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"

        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:clickable="true"


        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
         />
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView

        android:id="@+id/mapview"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:clickable="true"

        android:apiKey="0uZMgFMDqZETDVYg843CSoC8rHyuV01ypwz2C2Q"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, if I try with a TableLayout with a weight of "1", my list and mapview don't fill the height of my screen : http://img862.imageshack.us/img862/9442/bugzt.png

My current code : http://pastebin.com/t2ie9rs2

Answer (score 0):

Put your listview above the mapView.   Take out the alignParentLeft and alignParentRight properties in both views.  Then, in the mapview, add:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `android:layout_weight="1"` on both your `MapView` and `ListView`.